# I am unable to access class attribute in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

```
Implementation:
  <tr>
        <td class = 'show_hours'>{Number(this.props.showHours).toLocaleString()}</td>
       <td class = 'waiting_hours'>{Number(this.props.waiting).toLocaleString()}</td>
   </tr>



/*Testcase:


describe('RenderJobsRow',() => {
    it('Commas separated with Numbers.',() => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<RenderJobsRow
            showHours={23567}
            waiting  ={3214524}
        />)
        expect(wrapper.find('.show_hours').text()).toEqual('23,567')
        expect(wrapper.find('.waiting_hours').text()).toEqual('3,214,524')
    })
})
```

*
/*currently  error message:

/*Method "text" is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr>
   <td className = 'show_hours'>{Number(this.props.showHours).toLocaleString()}</td>
   <td className = 'waiting_hours'>{Number(this.props.waiting).toLocaleString()}</td>
</tr>
```